# Time-order in database transactions

Tags: database, transactions

i have always worked with concurrency control, but recently i have thought about how the non-determinism on the execution of transactions in a database can change the final result from the user's point of view.

Consider that two persons P1 and P2 both want to withdraw 50 euros from a bank account that has precisely 50 euros.

P1 requests the operation from an ATM at time 8:00
P2 requests the operation from an ATM at time 8:02

Both requests eventually arrive at the bank database system, but due to non-deterministic factors (transaction ordering, OS thread scheduling, etc) P2's request is executed first and the withdrawal is successful, and P1's request fails because it was executed after P2's request and hence there was not enough Money to withdraw.

We arrive at a situation where the person who first requested the operation ends without the Money. Are these concerns taken in account in real time systems? I hear some people saying that these things are not important and the world will go on, the only concern is to not violate the consistency constraints (no Money disappears, no Money magically appears)

Nonetheless, i think that this time-request fairness is also important.

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write extended answer to refer to these consideration in the future.

> Nonetheless, I think that this time-request fairness is also important.

**Is victory really unfair?**

In fact, the system is fair because time-request fairness is guaranteed based on which request was written to database first.

The only problem is that it is not explicit to users.

**Solution: set clear rules of the game**

Eventually, this is less about fairness of ATM system in providing adequate service. Instead, this is about **[SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)** it guarantees.

- If withdrawal transaction completes within maximum timeout of 5 minutes, all a person should do to guarantee his victory is to **be the first AND 5 minutes ahead of the other one to touch ATM**.
- Otherwise, in overlapping time intervals, the winner is selected randomly (as it appears).

Both rules are fair if they are agreed upon.

---

---

---

**DETAILS**

Article **["Race Conditions Don't Exist"](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/)** review similar example in **[CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)** context.

Guaranteeing absolute fairness is sometimes prohibitively expensive or completely impossible.

Ultimately, what matters is whether operational model is adequate to specific Domain.

**Is it fair for the system to let users judge about itself based on their own assumptions?**

We deal with multiple views P1 and P2.

Both views show only the money left at the time of balance request (**fair**). None of the views was given explicit guarantee that the entire sum was exclusively locked for this specific view (**fair**).

What may get users upset is their own communication (additional view) **outside the system**. For example, both person see each other and know exactly who was the first to submit withdraw request at its own ATM. System is not responsible for consistent views outside itself. Users are upset because they wrongly assume system selects winner based on them pressing ATM button first.

**How far can we go technically guarantee?**

System could lock entire balance the moment user touches ATM. There are lots of details why this is not practical. Most importantly, it may not satisfy those who assume it is unfair to lock balance without eventually withdrawing anything. And how to guarantee to acquire lock first by the user who touched the ATM first?

System could be designed to wait for candidate requests within timeout adjusted to maximum allowed delays in request propagation. Then it may have several candidates for victory and it may use timestamps given by source ATMs. However, even then there would be unfairness due precision of clock synchronization.

Effectively, first is never absolutely defined due to physics - see **[uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)** ;)